# Why I get 202 and 201 HTTP status when I rum my application

Tags: visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api2

I work on my SPA application I use web api and angularjs and visual studio 2015.

I set up IIS  in my web project, like that:

[image]

when I run the project in debug mode and open fiddler I get this rows:

[image]

those HTTP requests generated until I press stop debugging in Visual Studio.

Any idea why I get those HTTP requests?

Comment: This is a part of Visual Studio.

Comment: visual studio send data to client?

Comment: Different parts of Visual Studio communicating with each other over local HTTP.

Comment: I have another project very simular to the current but when I  open fiddler and the second project I don't get generated http posts like in screenshot above.
Maybe it's related to IIS configurations?